# Powershell Word ZOrder

Tags: powershell, ms-word, z-order

Powershell is ignoring my ZOrder commands.  It doesn't matter which method I use.  How can ZOrder be modified for a picture or shape added to a word document from powershell?

Method 1:

```
$Doc = $Word.Application.Documents.Open($docPath)
$Shape = $Doc.Shapes.AddShape(1, 0, 0, 612, 792)
$Shape.Fill.UserPicture("C:\pic.tif")
$Shape.ZOrder.msoSendToBack
```

Method 2:

```
$Doc = $Word.Application.Documents.Open($docPath)
$Shape = $Doc.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\pic.tif", $false, $true, 0, 0, 612, 792)
$Shape.ZOrder.msoSendToBack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZOrder is a functional call that takes an MsoZOrderCmd. So, you need to do:

```
$msoSendToBack = 1
$Shape.ZOrder($msoSendToBack)
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432726(v=office.12).aspx for the enum list.

Comment: Because I was looking to put it behind text, it actually required the MsoZOrderCmd = 5, but your answer got me on the right track.  Thanks!